# Selenium chromedriver doesn't execute a onclick event

Tags: python, selenium, jsf

I'm developing a bot to web scrape some info from a specific website.
In this website, we need to fill a dynamic form with:

- Health Plan (Select);
- State Address (Select)
- City Address (A dynamic select with data loaded by the previous field)
- Search By (Radio button)

In Chrome, this radio button takes us to another interface (with the same URL), but in Chromedriver it doesn't.

I've checked the code in this radio button, and has this onclick event:

```js
jsf.ajax.request('viewns_Z7_MPD81G80P843E0QQK0CK5L2GC1_:formInicio:tipoPesquisa',event,{execute:'@this viewns_Z7_MPD81G80P843E0QQK0CK5L2GC1_:formInicio:panelgrid-g-recaptcha-response ',render:'viewns_Z7_MPD81G80P843E0QQK0CK5L2GC1_:formBuscaSobreOMapa viewns_Z7_MPD81G80P843E0QQK0CK5L2GC1_:formInicio viewns_Z7_MPD81G80P843E0QQK0CK5L2GC1_:formInicio:panelGridSelectOneRadioTipoPesquisa ',onerror:mostrarErroGenerico,onevent:selecionarTipoPesquisa,'javax.faces.behavior.event':'click'})
```

How I can pass by this step?

*(I've tried run this javascript code in url bar, and do all steps manually, but don't work.)*

My entire code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Create a browser instance
gc = webdriver.Chrome()
gc.maximize_window()

# Open the url
gc.get('https://www.bradescoseguros.com.br/clientes/produtos/plano-saude/consulta-de-rede-referenciada')

time.sleep(2)

# Select "Non Client" mode
non_client = gc.find_element_by_name('viewns_Z7_MPD81G80P843E0QQK0CK5L2GC1_:formInicio:clNotClient')
non_client.click()

time.sleep(2)

# Get plans
lp = gc.find_element_by_id('lista-redes')
lp_list = lp.find_element_by_tag_name('ul')
lp_options = lp_list.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
lp_options[0].click()

time.sleep(2)

# Select states
le = gc.find_element_by_id('lista-estado')
le_list = le.find_element_by_tag_name('ul')
le_options = le_list.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

states_dict = {
    'ACRE': '00',
    'ALAGOAS': '01',
    'AMAZONAS': '02',
    'AMAPA': '03',
    'BAHIA': '04',
    'CEARA': '05',
    'DISTRITO FEDERAL': '06',
    'ESPIRITO SANTO': '07',
    'GOIAS': '08',
    'MARANHAO': '09',
    'MINAS GERAIS': '10',
    'MATO GROSSO DO SUL': '11',
    'MATO GROSSO': '12',
    'PARA': '13',
    'PARAIBA': '14',
    'PERNANBUCO': '15',
    'PIAUI': '16',
    'PARANA': '17',
    'RIO DE JANEIRO': '18',
    'RIO GRANDE DO NORTE': '19',
    'RONDONIA': '20',
    'RORAIMA': '21',
    'RIO GRANDE DO SUL': '22',
    'SANTA CATARINA': '23',
    'SERGIPE': '24',
    'SAO PAULO': '25',
    'TOCANTINS': '26'
}

# Select SP state
le_options[25].click()

time.sleep(2)

# Select cities
lc = gc.find_element_by_id('lista-cidade')
lc_list = lc.find_element_by_tag_name('ul')
lc_options = lc_list.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

i = 0
for c in lc_options:
    print('ID: {}\nCidade:{}\n'.format(i, c.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text))
    i+=1

lc_options[110].click()

time.sleep(2)

# Select a establishment
les = gc.find_element_by_id('lista-tipo-pesquisa')
les_options = les.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="radio"]')

i = 0
for r in les_options:
    print('ID: {}\nOpcoes:{}\n'.format(i, r.get_attribute('value')))
    i+=1

time.sleep(2)

les_options[2].click()

#gc.find_element_by_class_name('form').find_element_by_tag_name('form').submit()

# Close Browser
#gc.quit()
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is not going to work:  "non_client = gc.find_element_by_name('viewns_Z7_MPD81G80P843E0QQK0CK5L2GC1_:formInicio:clNotClient')"  I assume that's part of the "onClick" attribute, not the name.  Post the full form HTML

Comment: @pcalkins, this element "viewns_Z7_MPD81G80P843E0QQK0CK5L2GC1_:formInicio:clNotClient" is an anchor that open a modal box. My problem is three steps after, in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that tested and worked flawlessly.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("clNotClient").click()
# wait until the loading is done
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panelGridRecaptchaResponse[style*='display: none'] img")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panelGridRecaptchaResponse[style*='display: none'] img")))
listItems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#lista-redes  .list-group-item.ui-menu-item")
listItems[0].click()


# wait until the loading is done
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panelGridRecaptchaResponse[style*='display: none'] img")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panelGridRecaptchaResponse[style*='display: none'] img")))
npList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tbl-dados .list-group-item.ui-menu-item")
npList[25].click()

# wait until the loading is done
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panelGridRecaptchaResponse[style*='display: none'] img")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panelGridRecaptchaResponse[style*='display: none'] img")))
#cities
cities = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#lista-cidade li.list-group-item.ui-menu-item")
cities[-1].click()

# wait until the loading is done
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panelGridRecaptchaResponse[style*='display: none'] img")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panelGridRecaptchaResponse[style*='display: none'] img")))
# select radio
radios = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#lista-tipo-pesquisa input[type='radio']")
radioNumber = 1
for radio in radios:
    print ("Radion " + str(radioNumber) + ":- " + radio.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::label").text)
    radioNumber = radioNumber+1
radios[2].click()
```

[image]

Comment: How are you?
Thank you for your help! But I've tested this code and it still does not work.

If you check "manual flow", after the radio button the website changes interface, and both my code and yours cannot do it! :(

Comment: Can you please share the options that you are using for manual flow and the screenshot after selecting the radio button.

Comment: @subpputuri, in Chrome (not Chromedriver), it's like this:
[Link to GIF](https://i.imgur.com/bC8I5M6.gif)